# How to change the text label color according to its result?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

My App is presenting some score results and I would like to add a color variation of score labels from red to green according to the result :

```
self.scoreLabel.text = "\(total100)/100"
```

What is the easiest way to realize it ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this function when result change.

```
func setTextColor(score: Int){
    if score < 34 {
        self.scoreLabel.textColor = .red
    }else {
        self.scoreLabel.textColor = .green
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use attributed string

```
let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(total100)/100", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location:7,length:3))
    self.scoreLabel.attributedText = myMutableString
```